# Magento display category page as home page

Tags: php, html, magento-1.9

I have a category page in magento with the following url

http://miscstore.local/fancy-dress-party-supplies.html

[image: magento category page]

I want to set this exact page to be the homepage. I read a ton of posts and have tried about 20 things and can't get it working.

I have tried setting the content of the home page to the below

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"
>   template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

However the homepage then looks like the following

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to make http://miscstore.local/fancy-dress-party-supplies.html which is a url that works to be the default home page.

Comment: DId you try something simple like this? http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/1874

Comment: I tried what was in that post and got it working. Thanks very much appreciate the help. @CBroe